How to use Typescript Generics to infer type of object property
Given this simplified example code:
type People = {
    [key: string]: {
        names: (string | number)[];
    };
};

const people: People = {
    bert: {
        names: ["Bert", 1],
    },
    ernie: {
        names: ["Ernie", 2, "The Ern"],
    },
};

function getNames(person: People[string]) {
    return person.names;
}

const names = getNames(people.bert); // names: string | number


In this case, I would like names to be of type "Bert" | 1.
So it should be inferred from the names property of whoever I pass into getNames.
I am unable to figure out how I can use Typescript Generics to fix this.
Can somebody help me with this? Many thanks.
#edit
After the answer of @ caleth, i am thinking of an example closer to the actual use-case, I am wondering if a simpler solution exists.
When i have this code:
const tests = {
    test1: {
        variants: ["variant1", "variant2"],
    },
    // ...
}

function getRandomVariant(test) {
    // some random logic
    return test.variants[0];
}

const variant = getRandomVariant(tests.test1);
// variant must be of type "variant1" | "variant2"

if(variant == "variant1") {
    // ...
} else if(variant == "variant2") {
    // ...
}

How to make this typesafe and use generics to get variant to be of type "variant1" | "variant2"?

Does this approach work for you? You do have to change the type of people (if you annotate it as People then all hope is lost of retrieving the information you want, because you've thrown it away). Note that the output type is just "Bert" because TS knows you're accessing the 0 element which is "Bert".  I'd think that's even better than what you asked for, but if for some reason you don't want that, please [edit] to explain why. Anyway I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining, if it meets your needs. Let me know.

@jcalz You are right, it's not about the 0 element. I edited the post with an example closer to the actual use-case.

Does this approach work for you? You still have to use as const. If so I'll write an answer but please [edit] the question to ask only the version you are trying to ask and not both the old and the new version. Anyone interested in the old version can look at the version history. If it doesn't work for you, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes, this does indeed work. This sample in combination with your given solution helped me. Many many thanks.

First off you need to make sure that people is inferred to a type where people.bert.names still has that type, which means changing the definition of people:
const people = {
    bert: {
        names: ["Bert", 1],
    },
    ernie: {
        names: ["Ernie", 2, "The Ern"],
    },
} as const satisfies People;

Then we can write a helper type to pull out the element type from names:
type Names<T> = T extends { names: readonly (infer R)[]; } ? R : never;

Then we can put it all together with typing getFirstName:
function getFirstName<T extends { names: any }>(person: T): Names<T> {
    return person.names[0];
}

Playground link

Thanks @caleth, for this answer. Although it seems somewhat complex, it does look like this is what I need for my original example. I thought of another example, that's closer to the actual use-case. I edited my original question with another example...

@Xriter that's the same. You still need as const for the array to resolve to particular values
